# Uploading Sawtooth Software ACA Survey to web using personal website hosting

Tags: web, hosting, web-hosting, survey, programming-pearls

The software created a Web Upload folder for me, which I uploaded to the site using an FTP Client (specifically WS_FTP). The first lines of the pearl files say "#!usr/bin/pearl" that I changed to "/home/calakpsi/pearl". However, when I execute the html file it searches my computer under "/C:/Users/myname/AppData/Roaming/Ipswitch/WS_FTP/Storage/cgi-bin/ciwweb.pl". I made sure the file it's looking for was in that folder, but for some reason the webpage would still not execute.

Any help or step by step solution (since I do not have an in depth technical background) would be much appreciated.

Comment: specifically I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error (when the rest of the server is working perfectly fine), and a 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your server is not configured properly to run perl scripts. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560749/how-do-i-configure-apache2-to-run-perl-cgi-scripts), to see if it helps. The answer by Dave Sherohman should help you out.

Once you are able to run perl scripts, it should run (barring other issues which are script specific).

Overall the steps required to execute perl scripts are as follows. You can look up their details on the internet, as I don't know them myself.

- Install any mods required for server, for instance mod_perl, on ubtuntu it would be something like `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-perl2`. If you are in windows, perhaps take one of those bitnami or other LAMP installers. They should come installed with it.
- Configuration for server/virtual host, so that perl files in the directory are executed
- ensure they have correct permission (and you should be all set).