# How do you enable Perl on Ubuntu with Apache2

Tags: perl, ubuntu, apache2

I have installed ubunutu witha apache on my pc and everything works great except: I don't know how to enable perl, everything I have tried either gave me a server error or gave me a 403 for the perl scripts.

Please tell me how to enable Perl. Thanks!

Comment: This is a web server configuration issue, and is addressed in the documentation for Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Place your files in /usr/lib/cgi-bin, make them executable and change the owner and group to www-data:

```
sudo cp myscript.pl /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
sudo chown www-data.www-data /usr/lib/cgi-bin/myscript.pl
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/lib/cgi-bin/myscript.pl
```

I prefer to enable the "AddHandler cgi-script .cgi" line in /etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf by removing the "#" in front of it and setting "Options +ExecCGI" for the directories below /var/www where scripts should be executed. But beware: Everything executable ending with ".cgi" will be executed as a cgi script this way.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely not a problem with Perl. Rather, your Apache2 installation may not be configured to parse .pl or .cgi files. You should review the [Apache Web Server documentation](http://httpd.apache.org) as well as this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560749/how-do-i-configure-apache2-to-run-perl-cgi-scripts).

Comment: Where would I have to edit my configuration, I mean I don't want to read the entire documentation to get the answer to one simple thing?
I appreciate you helping me out but it would make it a bit easier if you told me what some of the possible things I would have to check for.

Comment: I made my answer generic because troubleshooting your issue with the amount of information provided was sheer conjecture. Sebastian gives you the next level of what you should try.