# Where to save perl CGI files?

Tags: perl, cgi

---

Where to save the user created perl CGI files?

I have currently using the location /home/httpd/cgi-bin location to save the perl files.

I also came across saving some perl files in /data/web/apache/cgi-bin.

Query:

Is it mandatory to save the perl file under cgi-bin location

Comment: None of my perl files are CGI scripts, and none of the web applications I've seen in the last 6 years were CGI scripts. Your question is weird.

Comment: i have got confused with where to save my perl files@melpomene

Comment: Are your files CGI scripts?

Comment: yes. my files are CGI scripts@melpomene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Query:
>
> Is it mandatory to save the perl file under cgi-bin location

No. It's configurable.

You can put them in any directory just make sure they are readable+executable by Apache.

```
<Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/somedir>
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

The above directive tells Apache to permit the execution of CGI files. You will also need to tell the server what files are CGI files. The following AddHandler directive tells the server to treat all files with the cgi or pl extension as CGI programs:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
```

See:

- [How do I configure Apache 2 to run Perl CGI scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560749/how-do-i-configure-apache2-to-run-perl-cgi-scripts)
- [Apache tutorial: Dynamic content with CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html)

Comment: OP had mentioned `/data/web/apache/cgi-bin` so I assumed he is using Apache.

Comment: In my system cgi-bin location is under following category(/var/www/cgi-bin).I want know here what kind of files will be saved@Chankey Pathak

Comment: Please go through the links which I have posted at the bottom of my answer. Everything you ask for is mentioned there.