# Apache HTTP server configuration for CGI directory

Tags: apache, cgi

Assuming the default options for the directories are defined by

```
<Directory "/path">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
</Directory>
```

When using the directive

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/path/cgi-bin/"
```

... is it required (or advisable or unsecure, etc) to also specify the option ExecCGI? e.g.

```
<Directory "/path/cgi-bin">
    Options ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

Comment: [serverfault.com](serverfault.com)

Comment: @user234461: Is this question different from [How do I configure Apache 2 to run Perl CGI scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/560749/774575)?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is necessary, because your allowing the Execution of CGI (hence ExecCGI). Its not unsecure, but default way of enabling CGI script execution in the said directory.